# Why am I unable to UPDATE a Postgresql table where I have a TRIGGER defined with BEFORE UPDATE

Tags: postgresql, triggers, notify, pg-notify

In PostgreSQL, I have a table with a trigger defined which calls a defined PostgreSQL function. The trigger is `BEFORE UPDATE`. With the trigger defined, I am unable to make updates to the table in question. If I redefine the trigger as `AFTER UPDATE` everything works fine. Any ideas as to why?
The table is similar to the following:

```
create table user (
id bigserial constraint pk_userprimary key,
username                 varchar,
hasreadinstructions      smallint,
hasstarted               smallint,
hasendeddataentry        smallint,
hasviewedresults         smallint,
email                    varchar,
firstname                varchar,
lastname                 varchar,
registrationdate         timestamp);
```

And the function is:

```
create function perform_notify() returns trigger
language plpgsql
as
$$
BEGIN
   PERFORM pg_notify('has_read_instructions', 'foo');
   RETURN NULL;
END;
$$;
```

The trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER has_read_instructions BEFORE UPDATE
ON user FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
perform_notify();
```

If I define the trigger with BEFORE UPDATE, as shown, updates to the table do not work, such as:

```
update user set hasreadinstructions = 1 where id = 1;
```

The result is UPDATE 0 and the value is unchanged.

If I change the trigger to `AFTER UPDATE`, everything seems to be fine and my update to the table works with the result being UPDATE 1 with the value being changed.

In this case, I don't particularly care if I use `BEFORE` or `AFTER`, but I'm at a loss as to why; so any help in understanding this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html):

> Row-level triggers fired `BEFORE` can return null to signal the trigger manager to skip the rest of the operation for this row (i.e., subsequent triggers are not fired, and the `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` does not occur for this row).

In other words, by returning `null`, you're aborting the `update` operation. Instead, you can return the new row:

```
create function perform_notify() returns trigger
language plpgsql
as
$$
BEGIN
   PERFORM pg_notify('has_read_instructions', 'foo');
   RETURN NEW; -- Here!
END;
$$;
```